# How to calculate the coefficients of $V\cap U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> [image: ![Image shows part of how to find the basis of <span class=]$V\cap U$">

I know it sounds stupid easy but I can't figure out since the text just skipped it
We have 
$v_1,v_2\in V$ and $u_1,u_2\in U$
where 
$V \cap U  => x = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2$ and $x = \gamma u_1+\delta u_2$

so we have $\alpha v1 + \beta v2 = \gamma u1+\delta u2$

but after calculation we will get $-\alpha + \beta = 0$ and $\alpha =\delta$.

How did we do so?

More details included in the provided image

Comment: Use _ to write subscripts i.e. write \$ u_1 \$ to write $u_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$\alpha (1,-1,1) + \beta (1,1,0) = \gamma (1,0,0) + \delta (1,0,1)$$
So:
$$ (\alpha,-\alpha,\alpha) +(\beta,\beta,0) = (\gamma,0,0) +  (\delta,0,\delta)\\
(\alpha+\beta,-\alpha+\beta,\alpha) = (\gamma+\delta,0,\delta) $$

Since we have here an equality, we can say that each coordinate produce a new equation. So, we can say that:

$$\alpha+\beta = \gamma+ \delta\\\alpha-\beta=0\\ \alpha = \delta $$

Comment: thanks for answering but I think you misunderstood the issue I am asking how to find the coefficients in other words how we figure out that $\alpha - \beta = 0$ for example 
thanks for answering anyway

Comment: $\alpha (1,-1,1) + \beta (1,1,0) = \gamma (1,0,0) + \delta (1,0,1) $ so $(\alpha,-\alpha,\alpha) + (\beta,\beta,0) = (\gamma ,0,0) + (\delta ,0,\delta ) $ and $(\alpha+\beta,-\alpha+\beta,\alpha)= (\gamma+\delta ,0,\delta) $. Since all coordinates must be the same, you have 3 new equations, $\alpha+\beta = \gamma+ \delta$, $\alpha-\beta=0$ and $ \alpha = \delta$

Comment: *clapping* oh thank you, never thought about it like this.
In case someone stumbles upon the post might you edit your answer with the correct answer please